# How to define following objective function in CVXPY?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

Here is the objective function I am trying to write in CVXPY:
[image: objective function]

where matrix F (nxn) is my variable, A and W are known matrices and lambda is a tuning parameter (that I set to 1).

I can't figure out how to use CVXPY functions like sum or cumsum for the second part of the equation, so I used loops:

```
F = cp.Variable((n,n))

temp_1 = 0
temp_2 = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        temp_1 += pow(A[i][j]-F[i][j],2)
for i in range(n):
    for i_prim in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for j_prim in range(n):
                temp_2+=W[i][i_prim] * W[j][j_prim] * pow(F[i][j]-F[i_prim][j_prim],2)
cost = 1/pow(n,2) * temp_1 + 1/pow(n,4) * temp_2
    
objective = cp.Minimize(cost)
prob = cp.Problem(objective)
prob.solve()
```

However, this seems to create an infinite loop and crashes my program.

TLDR: Can I use premade functions like sum or cumsum for the second part of the equation? If yes, how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any mathematical equivalence (for example, phrased in a matrix shape rather than element-wise) for the objective function? I believe your expression can somehow be expressed using Kronecker Product, but I can't find a quick solution how to. And the program (with random values for A, W) works well for me, no crash.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with small random matrices as well, and works fine for me. I should have tried that earlier. My data set might simply be too large... Thanks a lot for looking at it.

Comment: Sometimes CVXPY uses a large amount of memory. Here is another example: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/12/cvxpy-large-memory-allocation.html.